Lightning message channel error
This is my meccage channel code.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Acon Message Channel</masterLabel>
    <description>This is Lightning Message Channel</description>

    <LightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>AccountId</fieldName>
        <description>Id Of Account</description>
    </LightningMessageFields>

    <LightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>AccountName</fieldName>
        <description>Name Of Account</description>
    </LightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>

I am getting below error:

force-app/main/default/lwc/childAccount2/childAccount2.js  org.auraframework.throwable.AuraRuntimeException: Unable to retrieve metadata for descriptor: markup://c:__LightningMessageChannel__acon__c

I have imported like this :
import acon from '@salesforce/messageChannel/acon__c';


Your channel never deployed to the server. XML is case-sensitive, so your file must read:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Acon Message Channel</masterLabel>
    <description>This is Lightning Message Channel</description>

    <lightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>AccountId</fieldName>
        <description>Id Of Account</description>
    </lightningMessageFields>

    <lightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>AccountName</fieldName>
        <description>Name Of Account</description>
    </lightningMessageFields>

</LightningMessageChannel>

Notice the capitalization of lightningMessageFields.
Once you successfully deploy your LMS, the component should be deployable as well.
